# how to use Contains in where clause in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this:

```
        var myResult = uow.GetRepository<SLItemsCustomersCard, long>()
            .Query(x => x.CustomerId == customerId && x.SquareColor == squareColor)
            .OrderBy(x => x.BranchMapRang)
            .Select((r, i) => new { Row = r, Index = i })
            .Where(x => x.Index == visitCounter - 1).ToList();
```

but I want to achieve this in where clause:

```
.Where(x => x.Index.Contains(visitCounter)).ToList();
```

How to do this?

Comment: Why is the query you have not working?

Comment: The `visitCounter` need to be a `sequence` then you could do something like this `(x => visitCounter.Cotains(x.Index))`.

Comment: What is the type of `x.Index`?

Comment: what is the type of visitorCounter? because it looks like an int where if it is, there is no need for contains and simple == would do

Comment: @Magnus query is working. But I want to achieve something like IN clause in SQL server.

Comment: Is any of them a collection? If not I don't see how that would be possible nor desirable.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be misunderstanding what the `Contains` method does. I'm basing this answer on your earlier usage of:

```
Where(x => x.Index == visitCounter - 1)
```

In other words, `visitCounter` is an integer (and so is `Index`). But then you want to use it like this:

```
Where(x => x.Index.Contains(visitCounter))
```

Which does not make syntactical sense. An integer (`Index`) does not have a `Contains` function. It's not fully clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but your comment clarifies it a bit more:

> But I want to achieve something like IN clause in SQL server.

The `IN` clause in SQL requires a range of possibilities (a list of integers, in your case), and you're not working with a list of integers here. Furthermore, you have phrased it as `Index.Contains(visitCounter)` which would imply that you're expecting `Index` to be the list of integers?

That simply doesn't make sense. So I'll give you the answer that makes the most sense, on the assumption that you weren't accurate with your pseudocode:

```
List<int> visitorIds = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 99, 125 };
```

And then you can do the following:

```
.Where(x => visitorIds.Contains(x.Index))
```

To put it in words, this snippet basically tells the computer to "only give the items whose `Index` is mentioned in the `visitorIds` list".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains` like this:

```
int[] VisitorIds = new int[] {1,2,3}; //an array to check with

    .Where(x => vivitorIds.Contains(x.Index)).ToList();
```