# .NET MVC get all users with any of a list of roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this working to get all users with a given rol:

```
    var roleId = db.Roles.Where(m => m.Name == "User").Select(m => m.Id).SingleOrDefault();
    var users = db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roleId)).ToList();
```

but how to do it for more than one rol? for example to get all users with roles "User" or "Admin"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use Contains in where clause in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939240/how-to-use-contains-in-where-clause-in-linq)

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL or EF?

Comment: @NetMage Entity Framework

Comment: @Jim G. sorry I dont see how that answer my question... linq noob here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This may not be translatable by EF into SQL.

```
var roleIds = db.Roles.Where(m => m.Name == "User" || m.Name == "Admin").Select(m => m.Id);
var users = db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => roleIds.Contains(r))).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you! It worked with a couple minor changes: `var users = db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => roleIds.toList().Contains(r.RoleId))).ToList();`

Comment: @patsy2k I would suggest adding `ToList` to the `roleIds` definition in that case, otherwise you send multiple queries to the server, but I was hoping to keep everything `IQueryable` so it would translate to SQL with one query - are you using EF Core by change?

Comment: you mean moving _toList()_ to the end of the first sentence instead of inside the _where_ in the second sentence, right? I think I got it now. Using EF 6.1.3.

Comment: @patsy2k Yes. I am surprised EF 6.1.3 couldn't translate the code to SQL without `ToList` but I was testing with LINQPad/LINQ to SQL.